# How to get the default version of an application in unix

Tags: linux, python, version, defaults

Let’s say I have two versions of Firefox installed. What is the way to get the default version of firefox printed? I am running the script in python. Is there way to get the output into python?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that the "default version" is whatever is executed when you enter `firefox` in a terminal:

```
version=subprocess.check_output(['firefox','--version'])
```

Comment: This could be improved by indicating that python will run `firefox` with (some) $PATH, which dictates which Firefox will start.